# update query for more than one matched rows from source table in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables -  table1 and table2. The current condition of both tables is as below:

table1:

```
id   type mon   tue   wed   thu   fri   sat   sun  
1    ets  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
1    ets  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
1    eta  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
1    eta  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
1    cl   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
1    cl   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
2    ets  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
2    ets  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
2    eta  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
2    eta  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
2    cl   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
2    cl   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

table2:

```
id  ets eta cl
1   mon tue wed
1   thu fri sat
1   sun mon tue
2   sat sun mon
2   fri sat sun
```

Note that the names of the columns in table2 are column 'type' in table1.
I want to update table1 in such a way that columns mon-sun get updates for all those values found in table2 for the respective 'type' (i.e ets, eta, or cl) and table1.id should match table2.id.

The resulting table I want is like below for above data:

```
id   type mon   tue   wed   thu   fri   sat   sun  
1    ets  1     NULL  NULL  1     NULL  NULL    1 
1    ets  1     NULL  NULL  1     NULL  NULL    1
1    eta  1     1     NULL  NULL  1     NULL    NULL 
1    eta  1     1     NULL  NULL  1     NULL    NULL
1    cl   NULL  1     1     NULL  NULL  1       NULL 
1    cl   NULL  1     1     NULL  NULL  1       NULL
2    ets  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  1     1       NULL 
2    ets  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  1     1       NULL 
2    eta  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  1       1 
2    eta  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  1       1 
2    cl   1     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    1 
2    cl   1     NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    1
```

The UPDATE query I am applying is as below:

```
update a
set a.mon = case b.ets when 'mon' then '1' else '0' end,
a.tue = case b.ets when 'tue' then '1' else '0' end,
a.wed = case b.ets when 'wed' then '1' else '0' end,
a.thu = case b.ets when 'thu' then '1' else '0' end,
a.fri = case b.ets when 'fri' then '1' else '0' end,
a.sat = case b.ets when 'sat' then '1' else '0' end,
a.sun = case b.ets when 'sun' then '1' else '0' end
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = b.id and a.type = 'ets'
```

Consider first updating table for `table1.type = 'ets'` and respective values of ets from table2 matching with id at the same time.

The above query only takes the first matching value from table2 and updates that in table1 and not the rest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is where a.rownum = b.rownum ? There is no such column 'rownum'.

Comment: it is same colum id. i mistakenly typed rownum istead of id.

Comment: In table 1 all lines are duplicated. Why ?

Comment: not all the lines in table1 are duplicated there are other column having value different in each row. for an example you can take 'startdate'. so combination of 'id' + 'type' + 'startdate' will make a unique key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to "pivot" your table before updating:

```
with cte as (
    select
        t.id, c.type,
        max(case when c.value = 'mon' then 1 end) as mon,
        max(case when c.value = 'tue' then 1 end) as tue,
        max(case when c.value = 'wed' then 1 end) as wed,
        max(case when c.value = 'thu' then 1 end) as thu,
        max(case when c.value = 'fri' then 1 end) as fri,
        max(case when c.value = 'sat' then 1 end) as sat,
        max(case when c.value = 'sun' then 1 end) as sun
    from Table2 as t
        outer apply (values
            ('ets', t.[ets]),
            ('eta', t.[eta]),
            ('cl', t.[cl])
        ) as c(type, value)
    group by t.id, c.type
)
update Table1 set
    mon = c.mon,
    tue = c.tue,
    wed = c.wed,
    thu = c.thu,
    fri = c.fri,
    sat = c.sat,
    sun = c.sun
from Table1 as t
    inner join cte as c on c.id = t.id and c.type = t.type
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b27a/7)</kbd>**

another way to do this is pivot/unpivot:

```
with cte_up as (
    select id, 1 as value, type, name
    from Table2
    unpivot (name for type in ([ets],[eta],[cl])) as up
), cte_p as (
    select *
    from cte_up
    pivot (max(value) for name in ([mon], [tue], [wed], [thu], [fri], [sat], [sun])) as p
)
update Table1 set
    mon = c.mon,
    tue = c.tue,
    wed = c.wed,
    thu = c.thu,
    fri = c.fri,
    sat = c.sat,
    sun = c.sun
from Table1 as t
    inner join cte_p as c on c.id = t.id and c.type = t.type
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b27a/27)</kbd>**

Comment: great.thank you very much Roman Pecker. have to study hard "pivot" though.

Comment: Awesome. Second solution is good too. thanks for great help. :)